# Select SUM() SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get the total from a column with SQL but it's not working, can anybody see what I do wrong.

```
SELECT a.Artikelnummer
    ,a.Artikelnamn
    ,a.Antalperpall
    ,COUNT(*) AS AntalArtiklar
    ,SUM(e.Antalpallar) AS TotalPall
    ,SUM(e.Antalperpall) AS TotalStyck
FROM Artikel AS a
INNER JOIN Evig AS e ON a.ArtikelnummerID = e.ArtikelnummerID
WHERE (e.Datum <= '{0}')
    AND (a.Kundkund = '{1}')
    AND (a.Artikelnamn = '{2}')
GROUP BY a.Artikelnummer
    ,a.Artikelnamn
    ,a.Antalperpall
```

SUM(e.Antalperpall) AS TotalStyck: it is this one who returns a strange value. What I wanna do is take the integer value in each row and get a total from that.

OK I went down to the basement and visited the server, and I found the problem. I needed to multiply  with Antalpallar like this SUM(e.Antalperpall * ABS(e.Antalpallar)) . But it is still not working and I think it is becouse of the negative values.

[se data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcOMf.png)

so where it is negativ value in Antalpallar like this -1200 *-2 should be -2400 but i don't think it's doing that, or? It is stuff going in and out of a warehouse.

Anyhow, the final value of adding those togheter should be 14320, but i get one on 20 000 something and without ABS()(or with) a sum on 5000 something.

Anyone knows how to write this SUM(e.Antalperpall * ABS(e.Antalpallar)) to get the value i want?

Comment: what is the datatype of Antalpallar and Antalperpall??

Comment: It's not working means you get what? could you explain better what 'strange' value is? try to cast the field as int

Comment: could you show us some sample data, what is being returned from the sum with that sample data and what you expect so we can work out what is going on

Comment: it gives me minus like -16400. and it is an INT. Sum is supose to work for that right? How do i cast it as an int in a SQL question? One of the big problems are that I don't have direkt access the the data right now, it's on a server where the program is installed. if i can't solve it I have sit my as down in there basement but i rather not.

Comment: like this right SUM(CAST(e.Antalperpall as INT)) AS TotalStyck? I take the bike over and test it. get o alot of exercis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiply and SUM() MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693332/multiply-and-sum-ms-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try it by eliminating if there are any strange values (characters) in Antalperpall. Use sum(cast (e.Antalperpall as Money)) and in filterclause 
where ISNUMERIC( e.Antalperpall) = 1. If there are any stange values in the field, you will obviously get conversion error.