# multiply and SUM() MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm trying to do multiply two columns and SUM() all rows in a SQL SELECT but I can't get the right value. I think it is becouse of the negative values in the columns.

[image]

So were it is negative value in Antalpallar like this -1200 *-2 should be -2400 but i don't think it's doing that, or? It is stuff going in and out of a warehouse.

Anyhow, the final value of adding those togheter should be 14320, but i get one on 20 000 something and without ABS()(or with) a sum on 5000 something.

Anyone knows how to write this SUM(e.Antalperpall * ABS(e.Antalpallar)) to get the value i want? obviously there are something i've missed.

```
SELECT a.Artikelnummer
    ,a.Artikelnamn
    ,a.Antalperpall
    ,COUNT(*) AS AntalArtiklar
    ,SUM(e.Antalpallar) AS TotalPall
    ,SUM(e.Antalperpall * ABS(e.Antalpallar)) AS TotalStyck
FROM Artikel AS a
INNER JOIN Evig AS e ON a.ArtikelnummerID = e.ArtikelnummerID
WHERE (e.Datum <= '{0}')
    AND (a.Kundkund = '{1}')
    AND (a.Artikelnamn = '{2}')
GROUP BY a.Artikelnummer
    ,a.Artikelnamn
    ,a.Antalperpall
```

Comment: -1200 * -2? No, that should definitely not be -2400, it should be +2400, multiplying two negative numbers give you a positive number. Can you clarify what you're doing here?

Comment: The question is, if the second column denotes how many of something you have, what does it even mean to have a negative amount here? Not only do you not have these items in storage, you *owe* the supplier two of them?

Comment: The only reasonable way I can get a sum of 14320 is by only counting the ones with a positive number, so adding condition `AND (e.Antalperpall > 0)` or `AND (e.Antalpallar > 0)`, or both, will get you the number you want.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want to include `a.Antalperpall` in your `group by`? That will cause the pall with `1120` items to be listed on a separate row in the result set. If you need the nominal number of items you could still get that by specifying `MAX(a.Antalperpall) as Antalperpall`.

Comment: I get that Antalpallar can be negative for some reason, but how can AntalPerPall be negative?

Comment: The first action to take when saying "This is right" (the number 14320), is to understand **why** it is right, and/or **how** it is right. If you've been told "You should arrive at the sum 14320", talk to whoever told you that. If you know that the sum should be that yourself, and you know why, please explain how you came to that sum.

Comment: Because right now you're arguing similar to "2+2 should 5 because I say so" and that only works for large values of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fia Maybe you should do your calculation elsewhere first for example on paper or in Excel to ensure you know exactly what you should get. It would also help you figure out the order of the calculation before writing it in SQL. According to the figures shown the values you've stated seems to be correct i.e 22,720 for multiply then sum the figures as is, or 5,920 if you use the Absolute value of the second column. If both columns use absolute values then it will also give 22,720. If you're sure you need to get 14,320 then you may need to get clarification of the calculation needed or revise that number.  [image]

Additionally, your values may be wrong. You can get 14, 320 if the values for the 2nd and 3rd rows in the second column was -1 and 1 respectively.[image]

Comment: 14,320 was the nuber i got from the warehouse guy. The number 5920 must be the right one.  Thanx alot Richard for clearifying the whole math thing for me.

Comment: I'm new to this forum, how do I send a heart or something?

Comment: @fia No problem. Happy to help. Simply mark the response as the Answer or similar. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)